# Inconsistent views with mysql local connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, privileges

I cannot access my local MySql databases unless I run:

```
mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

The problem is, if I run it this way, I have no permissions/privileges to actually do anything to the database. When I run just:

```
mysql.server start
```

I can login, but the only database that is shown is information_schema

I have tried going into mysql both of these ways and flushing privileges. Changing passwords. Using the PHPMyAdmin gui. But to no avail.

Versions:
Operating System: MacOs Mojave
PHP: 7.2
MySql: 8.0.16

mysql login: 'root' and I have tried no password '' as well as 'password'.

I have been trying to get a laravel project spun up locally on a local database but due to this issue, I absolutely cannot get it working. Any suggestions?

Comment: try logging in with 'root' as both the username and pw. If i remember correctly mysql defaults to root/root as the initial un/pw

Comment: @Jdub When I try with root/root I get this:

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: did you start the server first?

Comment: Forgot that I had restarted my computer. I did and then I got: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
But then if I go and try with the actual password which I used 'password' for, it connects, but no longer has any of my databases except for information_schema

Comment: hmm it seems like you have some connection config issues. Using a tool like Sequel Pro to help troubleshoot. https://www.sequelpro.com/

Comment: So try leaving the `root` password BLANK

Comment: @RiggsFolly That did not work.